taqman probes to measure telomere length
Has anyone previously used the TaqMan probe 5'-FAM-AGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTA-MGB-NFQ-3' (or something similar in terms of targeting TTAGGG), which targets the telomere repeat sequence (TTAGGG), to estimate telomere length through RT-PCR?

Please carefully re-read the [Tour] for this site which makes it clear that it is a Question and Answer site about specific biological problems, NOT a chat site. "Has anyone used…?" is an attempt to start a conversation, not a biological question. It might be possible to convert this into a question (albeit starting the title with a capital letter) of the type "Can this probe be used to do such and such?", although evidence of your own attempt to answer the question by an internet search would need to be included.

I’m voting to close this question because it is an attempt to start a conversation, not a question in terms of SE Biology.

David, this is a specific and genuine question, and definitely not an attempt to start a conversation. If you believe it can be reworded more appropriately feel free to do so. Thanks.

As I wrote, even after reformulating you ned to show evidence of having tried to answer it yourself. I cannot do that for you. And while you are about it you should edit your title with a capital letter. As for conversation, a question that starts "Has anyone previously used…" strikes me as soliciting a reply from specific people in the community. If your meaning was "Are there any reports in the literature…" you should have written that, but, to repeat myself, you need to do the literature search to find out.

Ending up here suggests the literature search and colleague search has been exhausted. But hey, if you are so determined to shut this question and its exploration down then who am I (or reason for that matter) to stop you.  It's this type of nonsense that is slowly killing these sites whilst ensuring more and more people flock to AI regurgitation.

We expect new users to find out the procedures on this site and to follow them. The site aspires to providing something more than AI, or conventional dialogue sites, and that is why SE sites are different. They are different in encouraging improvement of questions (and answers) — through direct editing for typos/language/grammar, and by suggestions in comments. There are specific recommendations on research in Asking a Good Question for good reasons. Tell us what you have found about methods normally used to measure telomere length.
